# Trouble reveling objects using layer based colliderspheres C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having some trouble getting a mechanic to function correctly in my game. Basically I have two zones: Collidersight and Colliderfatal, defined by collider spheres that are attached to a artillery shell that is fired by a cannon. Essentially, I want any objects that are within the Collidersight zone to be revealed as long as they are within that particular zone, if they are outside that zone they should return to being invisible. If an object collides with Colliderfatal, then that object should be revealed perminantly, even after the shell has been destroyed. I have tried to initialize the gameObjects individually but this appears to be extremely confusing and not applicable to the situation. The gameobjects already exist within the scene and I am not instantiating them in. I have been told, that I may need to create a list of the gameobjects to loop inside the collidersphere as a potentional solution for this problem but I am totally lost on how this might be achieved.

here is the code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class zone : MonoBehaviour {

 public LayerMask m_SightLayers;
public LayerMask  s_FatalityLayers;
    public Vector3 m_Position;
    public float m_Radius;
    public float m_Force;
    public float s_Radius;
    public Vector3 s_Position;
    public Invisible1 revealenemy1;
    public Invisible1 enemykill1; 

    public float s_Force;

    public InvisibleKill makeDead;

    public GameObject EnemyCube1; 

    //public GameObject enemydead; 
    bool hasExploded;
    public bool inZone;
    public bool inKillzone;
    //public float removeTime = 5.0f;

    bool hasBeenhit;

    void Awake(){

    GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");  

    }


    void start (){

    makeDead = (InvisibleKill) EnemyCube1.GetComponent (typeof(InvisibleKill));

    revealenemy1 = (Invisible1) EnemyCube1.GetComponent(typeof(Invisible1));    

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision explode){

        if(explode.gameObject.name == "Terrain" || explode.gameObject.name == "EnemyCube" || explode.gameObject.name == "EnemyCube1" ){
            hasExploded = true;
        }

    }
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if (hasExploded == true){

        Collider[] collidersight;
        Collider[] colliderfatal;
        Rigidbody rigidbody;


        collidersight = Physics.OverlapSphere (transform.position + m_Position, m_Radius, m_SightLayers);
        foreach (Collider collider in collidersight)
        {
            if(collider.tag == "Enemy"){

                Debug.Log("stuff");


                }


            rigidbody = (Rigidbody) collider.gameObject.GetComponent (typeof (Rigidbody));
            if (rigidbody == null)
            {
                    continue;
                    }

            if(rigidbody.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"){
                inZone = true;




            if(inZone == true){

            revealenemy1.Reveal1(); 
          //  revealenemy2.Reveal2();
            //revealenemy3.Reveal3();


                Debug.Log ("hit");

                    hasBeenhit = true;


                    if(hasBeenhit == false){
                        hasBeenhit = false;
                    //  revealenemy1.Hidden();
                    ////    revealenemy2.Hidden2();
                //      revealenemy3.Hidden3();

                    }

            }else{

                }
                }

            }   
        //Debug.Log (hasExploded);
        colliderfatal = Physics.OverlapSphere (transform.position + s_Position,s_Radius,s_FatalityLayers);
        foreach (Collider collider in colliderfatal)
        {

            inKillzone = true; 
        rigidbody = (Rigidbody) collider.gameObject.GetComponent (typeof (Rigidbody));
            if (rigidbody ==null)
            {
            continue;   


            }
            rigidbody.AddExplosionForce (s_Force * -1, transform.position + s_Position,s_Radius);
            Debug.Log("hasbeenkilled");

                }


        }

        if(hasBeenhit == false){

            revealenemy1.Hidden();
            //revealenemy2.Hidden2();
            //revealenemy3.Hidden3 ();
        hasBeenhit = false;
        }

        if(inKillzone == true){

            //EnemyCube1.GetComponentInChildren (typeof(Invisible1));
            hasBeenhit = true;
            //revealenemy.renderer.enabled = true;
        //  makeDead.isdead = true; 
                //(typeof(Invisible1));

        }

        if(makeDead.isdead == true){

            revealenemy1.Reveal1();

        }


    }

  void OnDrawGizmosSelected ()  {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position + m_Position, m_Radius);
        //Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position + s_Position, s_Radius);
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {

        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;

        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position + s_Position, s_Radius);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply activate/deactivate the object renderers when they enter the *zones*?  You stipulate that objects that have entered the 'Fatal' zone are permanently visible, I took this to mean they are visible even if they leave that zone.

Visibility class to be placed on any object whose visibility you want to change:

```
public class Visibility : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool LockVisibility = false;

    public void SetVisible(bool state){
        if(LockVisibility)return;
        renderer.enabled = state;
    }
}
```

And the collision detection class.

```
public class CollisionRender : MonoBehaviour {
//example collision types
public enum CollisionTypes { Fatal,InSight };
public CollisionTypes CollisionType = CollisionTypes.InSight;

//turn renderer on.  
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    Visibility vis = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Visibility>();

    if(CollisionType == CollisionTypes.InSight){
        vis.SetVisible(true);
    }else if(CollisionType == CollisionTypes.Fatal){

        //if in 'fatal' zone, make visible and lock visibility.
        vis.SetVisible(true);
        vis.LockVisibility = true;
    }
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    Visibility vis = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Visibility>();
    vis.SetVisible(false);
}
}
```

I'm using triggers so your collider will need to have 'IsTrigger' checked to work.